# Derive a Recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Could really use some help with this.

For an integer $m \geq 1$ and $n \geq 1$, consider $m$ horizontal lines and $n$ non-horizontal lines, such that no two of the non-horizontal lines are parallel and no three of the $m+n$ lines intersect in one single point. These lines divide the plane into regions (some of which are bounded and some of which are unbounded). Denote the number of these regions by $R_{m,n}$. For example, $R_{4,3} = 23$.

Derive a recurrence for the numbers $R_{m,n}$ and use it to prove that

$$R_{m,n} = 1 + m(n+1) + \binom{n+1}{2}$$

Comment: I don't even know where to start

Comment: I would suggest starting with $n=0$.  How many regions do the horizontal lines divide the plane into?  You should be able to find a simple expression for that.  Now add in the non-horizontal lines one by one.  The first one starts by cutting one region into two, then cuts another region each time it crosses a line.  How many regions does it add?  How many lines will the second one cross?  This should suggest a recurrence in $n$

Answer (score 0):

Think about what happens each time you add a line of each type.  If you add a horizontal line, it will intersect each of the $n$ non-horizontal lines, but none of the $m$ horizontal lines.  On the other hand, if you add a non-horizontal line, it will intersect all of the existing $m + n$ lines.  After drawing a couple pictures of small cases, you will see that $l + 1$ regions  are added when a new line intersects $l$ lines at $l$ *distinct* points.  Since no three lines meet at the same point by assumption in the problem statement, we know each new intersection intersects at a new, distinct point.

Thus we have our recurrences:

$\begin{align} 
R_{m,n} &= R_{m-1,n} + (n + 1)\\
       &= R_{m,n-1} + (m + (n-1)) + 1
\end{align}
$

We will now prove that $$R_{m,n} = 1 + m(n+1) + \binom{n+1}{2}$$ via double induction.

Let $\mathbf{P}(m,n)$ be the statement that the assertion holds for $m, n$

**Base Case $\mathbf{P}(1,1):$**
It is not hard to see that we have $R_{1,1} = 1 + 1(1 + 1) + {1 + 1 \choose 2} = 1 + 2 +1=4$ regions.

**$\mathbf{P}(m-1,1) \Rightarrow \mathbf{P}(m,1):$**
$$\begin{align}
R_{m,n} &= R_{m-1,n} + (n + 1)\hspace{3mm}\text{ gives us,}\\  
R_{m,n} &= 1 + (m-1)(n+1) + \binom{n+1}{2} + (n+1)\hspace{3mm}\text{so we show,}
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
R_{m-1,1} + (1+1) &= 1 + (m-1)2 + \binom{2}{2} + 2=1 + (m-1 + 1)2 + \binom{2}{2}\\&=1 + m(1+1) + \binom{1+1}{2} \hspace{3mm}\text{as desired.}
\end{align}
$$
**$\mathbf{P}(m,n-1) \Rightarrow \mathbf{P}(m,n):$**
$$\begin{align}
R_{m,n} &= R_{m,n-1} + (m + (n-1)) + 1 \hspace{3mm}\text{gives us,}\\
        &= 1 + m(n) + \binom{n}{2} + (m + (n-1) + 1)\\
        &= 1 + m(n+1) + {n(n-1) \over 2} + n\\
        &= 1 + m(n+1) + {n(n-1+2) \over 2}\\
        &= 1 + m(n+1) + \binom{n+1}{2}
\end{align}$$
Thus by induction the formula holds for all $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$